# ruby Initializing instance variable outside method

Tags: ruby, variables, instance

As an experiment, I wrote some code that looks like

```
class MyClass

    @var = 100

    def hello
      p "hello"
    end

end
```

I know that if I do `MyClass.new` that `@var` is not defined on that object, rather I think this would define `@var` on the class `MyClass`.

Is there a practical usage to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *does* have a use: Class variables. The normal Ruby class variable implementation, `@@`, *shares* the same variable between a superclass and its subclasses:

```
class A
  @@v = 0
  def self.v; @@v; end
  def self.v=(val); @@v=val; end
end
class B < A; end
A.v #-> 0
A.v= 3 #-> 3
B.v #->3
B.v= 42 #-> 42
A.v #-> 42
```

Obviously, this is pretty useless (except for the fact that, unlike class instance variables, class variables are also accessible directly in instance methods, as opposed to through `self.class`). But the same example with class instance variables:

```
class A
  @v = 0
  def self.v; @v; end
  def self.v=(val); @v=val; end
end
class B < A; end
A.v #-> 0
A.v= 3 #-> 3
B.v= 42 #-> 42
A.v #-> 3
```

Also, class instance variables can harness all of the metaprogramming already written for instance variables, like so:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    attr_accessor :v #Uses a class instance variable
  end
end
```

Comment: your second example will not work, how would you call instance method on class receiver?

Comment: @kamal: Whoops. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

If you make accessor methods for `@var`

```
MyClass.singleton_class.class_eval { attr_accessor :var }
```

then you can treat `@var` like a class variable. The difference is that it won't be inherited by subclasses of `MyClass`.

_why takes advantage of this in [Dwemthy's Array](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/dwemthy/).